# percentage margin with constraintlayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm learning how to use `ConstraintLayout` and have found a few good tutorials to have views width and height in percentage. I know I can probably add an empty view to 'create' margin, but it doesn't seem right. Is there a way to things like `marginEnd='10%'`?

Comment: Either use weights in LinearLayouts or use PercentRelativeLayouts.

Comment: try guideline for divide screens or add view

Comment: `PercentRelativeLayouts` is deprecated, so I wanted to try if `ConstraintLayout` can do the job

Comment: yes, guideline is what I'm using to set height and width for the view, but how can i apply that to margin?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There're two ways to add percentage margin using ConstraintLayout.

### #1 Guideline

Simply add vertical [guideline](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7) to your layout and constraint view to that guideline:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### #2 Constraint weight

Add Space, place it on the very left side of parent, group your view and Space into ["spread" chain](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7) and set `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="90"` to your view and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="10"` to Space. It works very similar to LinearLayout's weight.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="90"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a result, your view has end margin with value of 10% of parent width:

[image: Result view]

Answer (score 9):

Trick #3:

for the percentage from both sides

```
 app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".80"
```

Comment: Note: This is relative to parent size, not relative to arbitrary sides.

Answer (score 9):

You might want nested constraints with

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
```

[image: screenshot without bias]
XML Example without bias:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: screenshot with bias]

Xml Example With bias

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#Bias

Comment: This should be the right answer. The bias between the start to the end of the parent